# MyBatis error: While updating a row in database

Tags: java, xml, jdbc, mybatis, ibatis

I am trying to update the database row using MyBatis. After configuring the MyBatis projects with POJO classes,DataMapper.XML and Mybatis-config.xml, I am not able to update the database.Need assistance on debugging the exception

The following is the exception,

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='revision', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.String, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #7 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
### The error may involve com.load.mappers.DataMapper.insertCADRelease-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: UPDATE XXXX_LOGS   SET STATE=?,   RELEASEDATE=TO_DATE(?,'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'),   ORIGINATED=TO_DATE('?','MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'),   MODIFIED=TO_DATE(?,'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')   where   TYPE=?   AND   NAME=?   AND   REVISION=?
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='revision', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.String, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}.
```

Follows the update definition in DataMapper.XML and POJO classes

```
<update id="insertXXXX" parameterType="XXXXUpdate">
        UPDATE XXXX_LOGS
        SET STATE=#{state},
        RELEASEDATE=TO_DATE(#{releasedate},'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'),
        ORIGINATED=TO_DATE('#{originated}','MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'),
        MODIFIED=TO_DATE(#{modified},'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')
        where
        TYPE=#{type}
        AND
        NAME=#{name}
        AND
        REVISION=#{revision}
</update>
```

The POJO class for setting the values for the object

```
public class XXXXUpdate 
{
  private String state,
  releasedate,
  originated,
  modified,
  type,
  name,
  revision;

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public String getReleasedate() {
    return releasedate;
}

public void setReleasedate(String releasedate) {
    this.releasedate = releasedate;
}

public String getOriginated() {
    return originated;
}

public void setOriginated(String originated) {
    this.originated = originated;
}

public String getModified() {
    return modified;
}

public void setModified(String modified) {
    this.modified = modified;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getRevision() {
    return revision;
}

public void setRevision(String revision) {
    this.revision = revision;
}  
}
```

The mybatig-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
 <properties resource="jdbc.properties"/>
 <typeAliases>
     <typeAlias type="com.load.objects.XXXXUpdate" alias="XXXXUpdate"></typeAlias>
 </typeAliases>
 <environments default="development">
  <environment id="development">
    <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
    <dataSource type="POOLED">    
   <property name="driver" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
   <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
   <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
   <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </dataSource>
  </environment>
  </environments>
  <mappers>
  <mapper resource="DataMapper.xml"/> 
  </mappers>
</configuration>
```

Please provide assistance on debugging the error. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around *originated* parameter:
  ORIGINATED=TO_DATE(**'#{originated}'**,'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'),